# Swift ! does not remove Optional()

Tags: swift, asynchronous, parse-platform, option-type

Before, I have successfully added a ! to force an unwrap to remove the "Optional()" from a variable. I am unable to do this in data returned from Parse.com

```
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {

            for object in objects {
                println(object[myObject]!)
            }

        } else {
            println("Error: \(error) \(error.userInfo!)")
        }

    }
```

In the example above, the entire table from the Parse.com class is returned and printed to the console. However,

> Optional(...)

is returned for each line even though I force an unwrap using ! at the end

What am I missing?

(Note: myObject is the name of the Column in the Parse Class database)

Comment: One possible explanation is that you are storing optionals in your object. When you access it with object[myObject], it gets wrapped in another optional. So you get Optional(Optional(something)).

Comment: You were right. I unwrapped the object into a new object and then unwrapped the new object and the Optional is gone

Answer (score 16, accepted):

MirekE was right. It was a nested Optional(Optional()).

to fix I:

```
println(object[myObject]!!)
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. :-) Don't forget to mark your own answer as the accepted (there might be a waiting period... not sure). The system punishes you for questions that haven't got an accepted answer.

Comment: in Swift 2, you only need one ! eg. print(object[myObject]!) to fix this problem, thanks for answer! :)

Comment: Excellent. I had print(array[1]["demo"]!) but the "optional(bla bla)" was still showing up, until I added a 2nd exclamation mark. I guess it was because I was accessing a 2D array.

Comment: How do I Add +10 to this Answer? ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You only have to put **"!"** at the end of your variable, in print area

```
self.addressLabel.text = "\(subThoroughfare) \(p.thoroughfare!) \n \(p.subLocality!) \n \(p.subAdministrativeArea!) \n)".
```